# Object destructuring with interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

Noob question but I'm trying to destructure an object the following way

```
interface ICount {
    one: string,
    two: string
}

const count = {
    one: "test",
    two: "hey",
    three: "morning"
}

const test: ICount = count;

console.log(test);
```

I'm expecting the *test* to be

```
{
    one: "test",
    two: "hey"
}
```

But it assigns *three* as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're just *type hinting* that `test` will contain an object with properties `one` and `two`, and it does that. You're not destructuring anything nor *limiting* what `test` can hold, as long as it does hold what the interface  dictates.

Comment: Read this too- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just typing the test object as an ICount type, you are not changing any value.

If you want to destructure the three value you can use simple javascript destructuring for that like this

```
const { three, ...rest } = count

console.log(rest) // { one: "test", two: "hey" }
```